# ASP.NET MVC 4 - CMS / CMS Components (like Wordpress)

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am developing a site in asp.net MVC 4 - code first, EF 5.

Areas of the site need CMS functions - but I need to drop MVC partials into the site - and would like to stick to MVC 4 (not MVC 2, or Web Forms, say).

Ideally slotting into an existing MVC 4 app - rather than taking over (but open to both).

Are there any MVC 4 'components' I can drop in - or full CMS's I could use?

Think ASP MVC 4 equivalent of Wordpress.

Requirements include:

```
 - Free / Low price (< $99) / Open Source
 - Good SEO optimization 
 - Easily adding multiple images to a page, and laying it out
 - Adding new pages to the website
 - Editing Navigation
 - Friendly URLs
 - Tagging
 - Social Sharing buttons with appropriate page titles
 - Drafts and future posts
 - RSS
 - Blog + Comments
 - Polling
 - Contact Form
 - Google Authorship Integration
 - All text on site editable
 - Image Gallery, click for larger image, thumbnails
 - WYSIWYG page editing - and templating
 - User friendly admin tools (ideally not requiring technical / HTML / CSS knowledge)
 - Storing all of this in a SQL Server 2012
```

Thoughts on whether just using Wordpress would be an big advantage? (I am semi-committed to MVC at this point - though if there are huge disadvantages may be persuaded to change).

Thanks

Comment: did you try http://www.orchardproject.net/ a cms based on asp.net mvc?

Comment: I have looked at it - and kooboo and umbraco - hard to select one?!

Comment: Umbarco is more of asp.net while kooboo and orchardproject is based on asp.net mvc. There are more support for orchard project.

Comment: I've decided to explore Orchard first thx

Comment: Composite C1 is what I ended up going for. I did in that in 2 hours what I couldn't do in a MONTH in Orchard. Super simple & super powerful. Orchard is WAY too complicated. Composite C1 is amazing - and free + open source. Can't recommend it enough.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried/checked out Piranha CMS? Open source, MVC 4 and Web Pages 2.0 with NuGet install. You can easily include it in your existing project and add content management to it. 
You can check it out at http://piranhacms.org/ or get it from directly from https://github.com/piranhacms

Comment: I haven't - how does it compare to Orchard CMS?

Comment: Interesting! Can't believe I never came across Pirhana CMS, for all the hundred times I've searched on "ASP.NET MVC CMS / Blog"! I've only done a 5 minute lookover, but it looks promising, thanks for the reference.

Comment: I am using Piranha CMS and it is really solid and light.

Comment: @Damir That is interesting, will take a look at this one. It is actually powered with ASP.NET MVC 5 right now.

Comment: Yes, and the upcoming version (2.3.0) will be pretty great too. It'll add support for modularization and also exclude the user management from the core. This means it'll be completely open to use other forms of authentication, like ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Looks interesting - anyone deployed this recently?